# Instagram notifications on my PHONE

Tags: notifications, instagram

I'm wondering how I can get the notifications to pop up on my phone, in the top bar. I've gone through all the settings and enabled all notifications but they do not notify me. With my twitter app, when someone mentions me in a tweet I get a notification on my phone in the top bar as well as in the actual app.
The notifications on Instagram only notify me of new comments/likes IN the app, not on my phone.
Help?